# Can't we use more than one custom object in vf template?

Tags: custom-object, related-list, relationships, visualforce-template

Can't we use more than one custom object in visualforce email template?..

Comment: is it possible to get the relatedlist records on vf email template. basically we need to avoid coding...

Comment: by using <apex:'relatedlist> ?

Comment: can u please share how it looks and paste the code here. i should not use code in my org thats my issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43121/discussion-between-reddy-and-ratan).

Answer (score 2):

Can I pull fields across objects on an email template?

**Resolution**
The Email Template function cannot process multiple objects.  From a custom object you can pull in all the fields that have a Parent Child relationship with fields on that object, otherwise it will not be brought in. Also related lists on an object will not be brought in on an email template.

### If you would like to see this feature, you can vote on it at: Sending an Email and Email Templates

Workaround: With the cross object formulas, you can create a field on the object that references that associated object. By doing this, the email template can then reference that field on the primary object instead of an entirely different object. Available after Summer 08 Release.

To display related list, see [Visualforce Email Template Sample](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/VisualForceEmailTemplates_sample)

Suppose you need to display Cases for Account then you can try this,

```
<messaging:emailTemplate recipientType="Contact"
  relatedToType="Account"
  subject="Case report for Account: {!relatedTo.name}"
  replyTo="support@acme.com">
  <messaging:htmlEmailBody>
    <html>
      <body>
        <STYLE type="text/css">
          TH {font-size: 11px; font-face: arial;background: #CCCCCC;
               border-width: 1;  text-align: center } 
          TD  {font-size: 11px; font-face: verdana } 
          TABLE {border: solid #CCCCCC; border-width: 1}
          TR {border: solid #CCCCCC; border-width: 1}
        </STYLE>
        <font face="arial" size="2">
          <p>Dear {!recipient.name},</p>
          <p>Below is a list of cases related to the account: {!relatedTo.name}.</p>
          <table border="0" >
            <tr > 
               <th>Action</th>
               <th>Case Number</th>
               <th>Subject</th>
               <th>Creator Email</th>
               <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
            <apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Cases}">
              <tr>
                <td><a href="https://na1.salesforce.com/{!cx.id}">View</a> |  
                <a href="https://na1.salesforce.com/{!cx.id}/e">Edit</a></td>
                <td>{!cx.CaseNumber}</td>
                <td>{!cx.Subject}</td>
                <td>{!cx.Contact.email}</td>
                <td>{!cx.Status}</td>
              </tr>
            </apex:repeat>                 
          </table>
          <p />
        </font>
      </body>
    </html>
  </messaging:htmlEmailBody> 
  <messaging:plainTextEmailBody >
    Dear {!recipient.name},

    Below is a list of cases related to Account: {!relatedTo.name}

    [ Case Number ] - [ Subject ] - [ Email ] - [ Status ]

    <apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Cases}">
      [ {!cx.CaseNumber} ] - [ {!cx.Subject} ] - [ {!cx.Contact.email} ] - [ {!cx.Status} ]
    </apex:repeat>

    For more information login to http://www.salesforce.com
  </messaging:plainTextEmailBody>    
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```